# How to let the Firewall of RHEL7 the SNMP connection passing?

Tags: rhel, iptables, firewalld, snmp

How to let the Firewall of RHEL7 the SNMP connection passing?

When I did this command on the computer:

```
systemctl stop firewalld
```

All the SNMP packet are passing well. When I restarted firewalld all the packet arre blocked.
I tried several connfigruation with the firewall running of course, like:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 161 -j ACCEPT
```

or

```
firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=161/tcp --permanent
```

I've not get any error message but the SNMP still in TIMEOUT.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The correct way to do this is to add a profile for SNMP to firewalld. Using UDP 161 not TCP

`vim /etc/firewalld/services/snmp.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<service>
  <short>SNMP</short>
  <description>SNMP protocol</description>
  <port protocol="udp" port="161"/>
</service>
```

Then you should reload your firewall

`firewall-cmd --reload`

Then you need to add the service to your public zone

`firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-service snmp --permanent`

Then finally reload your firewall again

`firewall-cmd --reload`

Comment: The command `firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-service SNMP --permanent` gives `Error: INVALID_SERVICE: SNMP`

Comment: did you reload your firewall after adding the snmp.xml ?

Comment: Sorry try snmp not SNMP, updated answer, copy paste fail.

Comment: I restarted the procedure from the beguining and it's working thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

SNMP is udp vs tcp. Change your protocol in your rule and it should work.

Comment: I  used this command changing tcp by udp but the port still  closed ` snmpwalk -v2c -c public computer system` ===> `Timeout: No Response from computer`

Comment: Are you also blocking outbound traffic on udp 161? Keep in mind that UDP traffic is stateless and you have to have a specific rule for it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to open the 161/udp port (instead of tcp) :

```
firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=161/udp --permanent
firewall-cmd --reload
```

Or use these commands to create a new SNMP service (adapted from [Documentation - HowTo - Add a Service | firewalld](https://firewalld.org/documentation/howto/add-a-service.html)) :

```bash
firewall-cmd --permanent --new-service=snmp
firewall-cmd --permanent --service=snmp --set-description="SNMP protocol"
firewall-cmd --permanent --service=snmp --set-short=SNMP
firewall-cmd --permanent --service=snmp --add-port=161/udp
firewall-cmd --permanent --service=snmp --add-protocol=udp
```

and then use your brand new SNMP service :

```bash
firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-service snmp --permanent
firewall-cmd --reload
```